# Display first n digits of a number in Java

Tags: java, int

I am having difficulty of creating a method to display first n digits of a number when 'n' is determined by the user.

For example, user inputs an integer '1234567' and a number of digits to display '3'. The method then outputs '123'.

I have an idea how to display the first digit:

```
long number = 52345678;
long prefix = number /= (int) (Math.pow(10.0, Math.floor(Math.log10(number))));
```

But I seem not being able to figure out how to display a user defined first n digits.

Thank you!

Comment: Why there are 2 equal to in this line `long prefix = number /= (int) (Math.pow(10.0, Math.floor(Math.log10(number))));`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int a = 12345;
int n = 3;
System.out.println((""+a).substring(0, n));
```

If you want a number:

```
int b = Integer.parseInt((""+a).substring(0, n));
```

Comment: Would have done the Integer.parseInt but I wanted to show the math behind it

Comment: Easiest, though I'd do a String.valueOf(a)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

```
String num = number + "";
return num.substring(0, numDigits);
```

If you need the number itself you can do

```
int div = Math.pow(10, numDigits);
while (number / div > 0)
    number /= 10;
```